# Search Api, filter by parameter

Tags: 2013, search, javascript, rest

I'm using the Search Api to get the last modified documents by the person using the search.
My search string is looking like that:

```
https://www.intranet.i/site/_api/search/query?querytext='* author:<UserName>'&rowlimit=5&sortlist='LastModifiedTime:descending'&refinementfilters='IsDocument:true'
```

But there were no search results returned, any advice?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the "show-stopper" is the use of the * in your query.

Try it like this instead:

```
https://www.intranet.i/site/_api/search/query?querytext='author:<UserName>'&rowlimit=5&sortlist='LastModifiedTime:descending'&refinementfilters='IsDocument:true'
```

You should be able to use the wildcard (*) together with a porperty name though, like

```
author:*
```

I have found this tool https://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/, which helps you construct and try your queries :)

**Edit**
Seems you are also having problems with the `refinementfilters` part. In this case I think you should add that part to your `querystring` instead:

```
https://www.intranet.i/site/_api/search/query?querytext='author:<UserName> IsDocument:true'&rowlimit=5&sortlist='LastModifiedTime:descending'
```

Comment: thanks. without the refinementfilter it works fine, but with the refinementfilter i'm getting no results

Comment: Can't you just add the refinement filter to your querytext instead?

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)